# How to retrieve certain files inside a folder containing many sub-folders and files python

Tags: python

I have a main folder, containing many folders and files. I need to get the paths to certain files scattered in the files, for example, I'd like to get the paths for all the files named: `summary.txt`.
Any idea how to do it in a simple way?
I'm using python 3.6

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `recursive` keyword of [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to search recursively using the `**` pattern.  Try

```
from glob import glob
print(glob("**/summary.txt", recursive=True))
```

This feature was introduced in Python 3.5

The above assumes that the interpreter is running in the target directory.  You can instead use absolute paths

```
print(glob("/path/to/directory/**/summary.txt", recursive=True))
```

Comment: Where do I put the path of the main folder?